# best way to merge rows that have matching ids

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

i have a table of households which has the address information and city info
and then i have and individuals table of all the people in the household
it could be 1 person that belongs to the house hold or it could be 10
what i want to achieve is that if the individuals belong to the same household there information will show up in the same row as the household information all in 1 row 
so if theres 10 people the inforamtion will still be in 1 row, if theres 2 people still only 1 row

```
   household table  
    1 bekshire st   dell    MA  10001   02639   50  0002    dell    NULL    ALRGEN  

    BERKSHIRE ST    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL  

    individuals that belong to household id 10001 

    first    last     code
    BOB       BUILDER  U 
    JESS     BUILDER  A  

    i want  

    1 bekshire st   dell    MA  10001   02639   50  0002    dell    NULL    ALRGEN  1   BERKSHIRE ST    BOB,JESS    BUILDER U,A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is so hard is that SQL favors normalization and structure, and essentially what your asking for is to go the opposite direction. I know I'm not directly answering your question, but maybe your best bet is to consider manipulating and displaying the data on the client side and stick to simple queries to get the data from the database.